# Display all the inner blocks when using "target" in CSS

Tags: css

I created tabs in HTML/CSS. Those tabs are hyperlinks that target blocks ("div") on click. The content is not displayed for inner blocks (sub-blocks) not sure why.

```
<div id="contents">
    <div id="content1">
        <div>content not displayed</div>
    </div>
    <div id="content2"> content displayed </div>
    <div id="content3"> content displayed</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML looks fine. There must be some CSS hiding it. Developer tools in your browser should help you track it down.

Comment: Paste your css also and we will be able to help you.

Comment: CSS:
#contents div {border: 1px black dotted;display: none;}
#contents div:target{display: block;}

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to come from the CSS.
You have :

```
#contents div {
    border: 1px black dotted;
    display: none;
} 
#contents div:target {
    display: block;
}
```

which hides all div inside contents and their children, and when targeted you only change the display of the div, not it's children. So the div inside content1 is never displayed.

There are many ways to fix this.

One way would be to only hide the direct children of #contents :

```
#contents>div {
    border: 1px black dotted;
    display: none;
}
```

Another way would be to only hide div that have an id :

```
#contents div[id] {
    border: 1px black dotted;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Chrome right click on the element and select inspect, in the dev tools that open look for the css style that is causing your issue.

Comment: In CSS style i am doing two things:  1 "display none" for #contents div. 2- "display block" for #contents div.

The code works fine, only inner blocks are ignored

Comment: @zimo Please edit your post to inlcude your css rather then comment it on this answer it makes it really difficult for anyone who comes to your question in the future to help or gather the information they may need to help. :)

Comment: CSS:
#contents div {border: 1px black dotted;display: none;}
#contents div:target{display: block;}